# What is a more readable version of this slideshow code?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn by making my own jQuery slideshow based on existing open source code on the net.

I am getting lost in one chunk of coding and I think it's mainly because I am not very strong to begin with in programming/jQuery, and also the guy who wrote it used a bunch of ternary operators (I believe that's what this is).

Could someone please help me break this down and maybe even replace the ternary operators with more "traditional" operators?

```
//if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
var current = ($('ul.slideshow li.show') ?  $('ul.slideshow li.show') : $('#ul.slideshow li:first'));

//Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption') ? $('ul.slideshow li:first') :current.next()) : $('ul.slideshow li:first'));
```

I am mostly confused on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it helps to indent things.

```
var next = (
  (current.next().length) ? (
    (current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption') ?
      $('ul.slideshow li:first')
      : current.next()
    )
    : $('ul.slideshow li:first')
  );
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
var next;
if (current.next().length) {
  if (current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption') {
    next = $('ul.slideshow li:first');
  } else {
    next = current.next();
  }
} else {
  next = $('ul.slideshow li:first');
}
```

Comment: Ok please excuse me if i get too specific but again I am trying my best to learn.  I put "alert(current.next().length);" above and it kept alerting "1". I thought that length was suppose to tell me how many elements matched the selector??? Could you tell me what length is doing above?

Comment: As well, in the center: "next = current.next();" Would you mind telling me what current.next() is doing?  Again I thought next() was used to select the next element?

Comment: `length` will tell you how many elements are in that jQuery object. So `current.next().length` will return `1` if there is an object returned by the `next()` method.  If it's the last element in it's parent, then next will return a jQuery with no elements in it, and a `length` of `0`.  And `0` is considered false in `if (0)`.  So `if (current.next().length)` basically asks "if the current is not the last element"

Comment: The whole point of this snippet is to assign the element after the current one to the `next` variable.  So `next = current.next();` is what actually does that.  After that line runs, `next` holds a reference to the element after `current`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, youve been a great help. Can I ask you, do you think the guy wrote all of this code in shorthand from the get go or do you guys write the code indented, then once it works as expected, convert it to shorthand?

Comment: Code readability is important if anyone else will ever have to edit your code.  And nested ternaries fail in readability.  Use them when it's simple and clear, otherwise they just get confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
//if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
var current;
if ($('ul.slideshow li.show').length){
  // if we found an item with the show class, assign it to current
  current = $('ul.slideshow li.show')
}else{
  // otherwise nothing is being shown, default to first element
  $('#ul.slideshow li:first');
}

//Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
var next;
// if there are additional elements (true when .length > 0)
if (current.next().length){ 
  // is the next element the slideshow caption
  if (current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption') 
    // it is, so go back to the first element
    next = $('ul.slideshow li:first')
  // it's not, continue on with the next element
  else
    next = current.next();
}else{
  // there is no next element, go back to first.
  next = $('ul.slideshow li:first');
}
```

Comment: I think there was an error in the OP that made it into this code. The first if check should be `if($('ul.slideshow li.show').length)`.